# RAILS_ENV=demo bundle exec rake assets:precompile not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have added some images and js, after that tried to compile the assets and when I have ran the command `RAILS_ENV=demo bundle exec rake assets:precompile` on my development server but it does nothing

```
box-admin@demoone:/var/www/sites/ecopractices/current$ RAILS_ENV=demo bundle exec rake assets:precompile
box-admin@demoone:/var/www/sites/ecopractices/current$
```

Can anybody suggest any solution?

Comment: What about your `public/assets/` directory? What's this content? assets:precompile doesn't give any output by default.

Comment: In public/assets all images and js are there ..!!

Comment: I have added images into app/assets/

Comment: So your problem doesn't exist and everything works as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Update your `config/initializers/assest.rb`:

```rb
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js *.scss *.css.scss *.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif *.woff *.ttf *.svg *.eot)
```